# RStudio won't start, R ver. 3.4.2, Rstudio ver. 1.1.383

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm not able to start a fresh installment of RStudio. I've deleted prior versions, and are currently only running R ver. 3.4.2. Likewise I've deleted my .RData file, but nothing seems to work. The program doesn't show anything, but it is listed on running programs, and the more times I click the more times it opens a new RStudio, untill it clogs the CPU. I'm running Windows 10.

What to do?

[image]

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you have anything else running at the time?

Comment: Dang, forgot that. I'm running Windows 10. I have nothing of importance running, but are you specifically thinking of something?

Comment: It's seems as if it's running in the background, because it shows up in the joblist, but there's just no window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid that this idea will help you or not that you can try this. 
Uninstalling RStudio and R, **cleaning the registry**, and installing again.
If it is running then close it first from the task manager then uninstall the program.

Comment: I've just uninstalled everything, deleted every .Rdata file, and reinstalled R and RStudio, but it's still just running in the background, and I can open multiple iterations until it clogs the memory. Same as before uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: If it running then try to close it first. Type 'tasklist' in the command prompt. Then find the running process for RStudio and R. Then kill those process.

Comment: I've killed the processes several times, and everytime before starting again. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: Have you checked startup program list?

Comment: How do I clean the registry?

Comment: Please go to this link: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-edit-registry-using-command-prompt-windows-10